# Filter values of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanna filter values of dictionary.

```
d1 = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 8, 'd': 7}
```

What is the pythonic way to do that.

```
d={}

for k,v in d1.items():
   if v>0:
      d[k]=v
```

I couldn't use filter to get the same reuslts.

```
filter(..)
```

Is there any elegant pythonic way to do that ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension, to create a dictionary with the filtered values, like this

```
>>> {key: d1[key] for key in d1 if d1[key] > 0}
{'c': 8, 'd': 7}
```

You can also use `dict.items()` like this

```
>>> {key: value for key, value in d1.items() if value > 0}
{'c': 8, 'd': 7}
```

Note: Using `dict.iteritems()` will be more memory efficient in Python 2.7, as `dict.items()` will create a list of tuples with all the key-value pairs.

If your intention is to just remove the values which are `0`, then you can even shorten it like this

```
>>> {key: value for key, value in d1.items() if value}
{'c': 8, 'd': 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

filter function method to fullfill your requirement.

```
def f(x):
    return x[1]>0
d1 = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 8, 'd': 7}
filter(f, d1.items())
```

Or you can use lambda function, like this, it is simpler:

```
filter(lambda x:x[1]>0, d1.items())
```